# How i parse json data in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am getting some json data from another server, how parse this data in java

```
[
  "user bank data",
  "user daily data",
  "Sports Lovers",
  "Work: Startups",
  "Art",
  "Volunteer Activities"
]
```

please provide some sample code to parse in java object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with gson:

```
// untested
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] array = gson.fromJson(jsonstring, String[].class);
```

where **jsonstring** is you input data.

Comment: @M.Suurland It is a json array, you cann't make it a object.. Oli is right..

Comment: thanx @Oli  its working for me.